# How To Calculate the Exact Amount Of Tokens Out One Would Receive when using Pancake Swap SDK

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

When Using Pancake Swap SDK

The Following Function

```
  const exactOut = new Trade.bestTradeExactOut(
          [pair_0_1],
          token0,
          new TokenAmount(token1, parseFloat(amountOut.toString(), 18)),
          { maxNumResults: 3, maxHops: 1 }
         
        )
```

we receive the following response

```
 outputAmount: TokenAmount {
    numerator: JSBI(1) [ 100, sign: false ],
    denominator: JSBI(2) [ 660865024, 931322574, sign: false ],
    currency: Token {
      decimals: 18,
      symbol: 't1',
      name: xxx,
      chainId: 56,
      address: 'xxx'
    },
    token: Token {
      decimals: 18,
      symbol: 't1',
      name: xxx,
      chainId: 56,
      address: 'xxx'
    }
  },
```

based on the above response how does one calculate the exact amounts of tokens one would receive out based on returning result from SDK call do we perform a calculation on?

```
denominator: JSBI(2) [ 660865024, 931322574, sign: false ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Needs To Use The Following Function

`parseBigintIsh(denominator)`